# Calling a base-class non-virtual function which has been redefined?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know some think I shouldn't redefine non-virtual functions from inherited classes, however, what I'm doing now is using that very role-migration concept, and it is fairly special case where it fits quite nicely.

What I want is this (oh, and this is C++):

```
class A {
 public:
 void f() { doSomethingA(); }
};
class B : public A {
 public:
 void f() { A::f(); doSomethingB(); }
};
```

However, when I do this, `A::f` gets called with `this == 0`, which obviously results in segfault. Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible? My current option is to resort to static functions and pass the object explicitly, but I'd prefer it this way.

Yes, I could call them differently, but that kind of defeats the purpose of making them look similar to the programmer. And I can't make them virtual for various reasons (the most prominent being the role-migration, that I actually want different behavior depending on what I use it as).

Any help appreciated

**EDIT**
Thank you all for answering, it appears I've stumbled upon a bug in my build environment, a minimal test case ran fine; and so did turning of optimizations. I guess I could have tried that before asking the question, but I usually assume I'm doing something wrong.

Nothing more to see here, move along.. Sorry for the inconvenience... :)

Comment: Your `B` doesn’t inherit from `A` … typo? Apart from that, this code should actually work.

Comment: @Konrad; I've double checked and there's no typo in the code, and yet I'm staring at the call stack in gdb where it clearly states `B::f(this=0xffbfdb40)` followed by `A::f(this=0x0)`.

Comment: This should work (when adding `;` after the class declarations). Can you give some minimal example the reproduces the problem?

Comment: @sth; Haha, I always miss those, sorry, fixed that..

Comment: What is the compiler, platform, etc, etc?

Comment: @nakiya: Solaris/Sparc with GCC 3.4.3

Comment: @roe: I suppose that your code is more complex than this, and the bug is not posted. If you try the code as it is posted you will see the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `B` not inheriting from `A` is a typo (I can't see this compiling otherwise), it looks like the `B` pointer on which you originally call `f` is null. Check the original call point, because (assuming the typo) what you wrote should work.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo, sorry. I've double checked and there's no typo in the code, and yet I'm staring at the call stack in gdb where it clearly states `B::f(this=0x123123)` followed by `A::f(this=0x0)`.

Comment: Can you expand your code slightly into a small fully runnable example that exhibits the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seem to fit with the text very well. In the text, you talk about inheritance, but the code doesn't show any (and at least as-is, it shouldn't even compile).

If you do use inheritance:

```
class A { 
public:
    void f() { doSomethingA(); }
};

class B : public A { 
public:
    void f() { A::f(); doSomethingB(); }
};
```

Then when you invoke `A::f()`, `this` definitely should *not* be a NULL pointer -- it should be a valid pointer to the `A` "subobject" in the `B` object (as long as you use single inheritance, with most compilers it'll be the address of the object on which you invoked `B::f()`, just cast from `B * const` to `A * const`).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
static_cast<A*>(this)->f()
```

Should work.

EDIT:

If it doesnt, check for `this` in `B::f()` first of all.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify that B inherits from A:

```
class B : public A {
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo, sorry.

Comment: this could have been just a comment, it does not answer the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the "correctness" of doing this, there is nothing wrong with what you're describing.  I'm assuming your example code would look more like the following though to actually have the inheritance you describe:

```
struct A {
 void f() { cout << "hi" << endl; }
};
struct B : public A {
 void f() { A::f(); }
};
```